# Why am i having issues 'make install' RXTX on Raspbian with Java 1.8

Tags: java, arduino, raspberry-pi, rxtx

I am trying to run a Java program which uses `gnu.io`.

This is failing because RXTX has not been installed correctly.

I went to the [FAQ](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ).

And subsequently changed the `configure.in` file to be extended to 1.8*

But I am still getting the same error telling me that `librxtxRS485.la` is not a directory.

How do I solve this issue??

Comment: I do not suggest using RXTX, you might face problems, look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979305/java-serialport-close-blocks/31899877#31899877

Answer (score 0):

You can try install RXTX library from repository:

```
sudo apt-get install librxtx-java
```

and run application

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni Class.class
```